# Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard issue - NetBeans is not showing Configuration File

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

Netbeans does not show the **hibernate.cfg.xml** configuration file in the *Configuration File* drop-down menu of the *New Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard* window, as shown in this screen shot:

[image: Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard Screenshot]

However, the connection configuration for the database works fine, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: DB connection OK]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">oracle</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_catalog"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: [1] I'm not sure whether NetBeans officially supports the use of Hibernate at the moment, due to licensing issues. See unresolved NetBeans issue [2719 Resolve Hibernate Support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2719). [2] Your question looks like a duplicate of [Hibernate Reverse Engineering on NetBeans does not detect hibernate.cfg.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70930333/2985643), though that is for NetBeans 12.5, and has no answers.

Comment: Same problem here...